# Can we get the [reference] <-> [references] tag synonym approved?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

[references](/questions/tagged/references) has 1,110 questions and a decent tag wiki.

[reference](/questions/tagged/reference) has 2,290 questions and no tag wiki.

There's already [2 votes for this to be approved](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reference/synonyms), can a couple people go vote it up (who can) or maybe a moderator, so we can push this through?

I know there are a few questions out there that use [reference](/questions/tagged/reference) to signify that the question is a "reference" question (a bunch of information), but honestly that should be removed because it's being used as a meta tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completed: [references](/questions/tagged/references) --> [reference](/questions/tagged/reference)